# When to assume exponential distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a system which can service requests at constant rate (`x requests / s` for example).

The exponential distribution has this property rate: the average number of item serviced per unit of time is constant.

I wonder if I can assume my server has exponential distribution?

Answer (score 0):

You probably **can** assume that.  The question is whether it is a good idea to do so.

It's unlikely that your system's service time actually has an exponential distribution.  Nevertheless, assuming an exponential distribution might be convenient. Without knowing a lot of details of the particular application
you're looking at, it's hard to say how badly any deviations from the exponential distribution might affect your results.

Comment: Thank you, could you be clearer on what characteristic of the system should I look into in order to determine the right distribution ?